# javascript vowels to uppercase and consonants to lowercase

Tags: javascript

The question I'm doing is:

> Write a JS program which takes 1 input from the user: a sentence (string). The program contains a function which converts the vowels (a,e,i,o,u) in the string to uppercase and consonants (non-vowel characters) into lowercase. Sample Input: string = "Learn programming and start earning". Expected Output = "lEArn prOgrAmmIng And stArt EArnIng". Your output code should be in the format console.log("Result is ", Output variable).

And my code is:

```
var sentence=prompt("Enter the sentence");

function convert(x){
 var a = x.split('');
 for( var i=0 ; i<a.length ; i++){
    if(a[i]=="a"){
        a[i] = a[i].toUpperCase();
    }
    else if(a[i]=="e"){
        a[i] = a[i].toUpperCase();
    }
    else if(a[i]=="i"){
        a[i] = a[i].toUpperCase();
    }
    else if(a[i]=="o"){
        a[i] = a[i].toUpperCase();
    }
    else if(a[i]=="u"){
        a[i] = a[i].toUpperCase();
    }
    else{
        a[i] = a[i].toLowerCase();
    }
  }
  var b = a.join('');
  return b;
 }

var output = convert(sentence);
console.log("Result is ", output);
```

It doesn't look good but provides output. However, it does not pass all test cases according to the webapp. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: For what input does it not provide the desired result?

Comment: It fails for initially capitalized vowels: HI becomes hi

Comment: Simply speaking, with your if conditions, you are treating uppercase vowels same as consonants.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to match vowels in lower and upper case, so you should compare in an incasesensitive way.

This alternative uses a regex which matches vowels in lower and upper case.

```js
let convert = (str) => {
  return str.split('').reduce((a, c) => a + (/[aeiou]/i.test(c) ? c.toUpperCase() : c.toLowerCase()), "");
}

console.log("Result is", convert("Learn programming and start earning"))
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code fails for initially capitalized vowels.
For example:
`convert("HI")` returns "hi"

You should convert the input to lowercase first:

`convert("HI".toLowerCase())` returns "hI" which is correct

Comment: why does this happen?

Comment: JS is a case sensitive language. Hence, if I pass "HI" to your function, "I" does not equal "i", and your else block will be called, hence the result is wrong

Answer (score 0):

```js
function vowelsCAP(str){
    var str;
    var res=str.split("");
    for(var i=0;i<res.length;i++){
        if(res[i]=="A"|| res[i]=="E" || res[i]=="I" || res[i]=="O" || res[i]=="U"){
          res[i]=res[i];
        }
       else if(res[i]=="a"|| res[i]=="e" || res[i]=="i" || res[i]=="o" || res[i]=="u"){
             res[i] = res[i].toUpperCase();}
        else{
             res[i] = res[i].toLowerCase();}
  } var out = res.join("");
    return out;
 } console.log(vowelsCAP("HI Bro, Learn programming and start earning"));
```

Comment: While this may answer the question it would be better if you explain how it works and solves the problem.